# Duplicate unique keys have been allowed into my Azure SQL database table

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have a large SaaS system database, running for 8+ years, no problems. It is an Azure SQL database, and we host the corresponding web application through Azure too.

Suddenly, in the early hours of this morning, some of the C# web app reports start failing due to duplicate table records being detected. I check the table in question and yes, there are duplicate identical records, with clashing unique keys, in the table.

I've never seen this before. How can a unique key fail to enforce itself during inserts/updates?

EDIT:
Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [tenant_clientnamehere].[tbl_cachedstock](
[clusteringkey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[islivecache] [bit] NOT NULL,
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[stocklocation_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[stocklocation_referencecode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[stocklocation_description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[productreferencecode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[productdescription] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[unitofmeasurename] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[targetstocklevel] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[minimumreplenishmentquantity] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[minimumstocklevel] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[packsize] [int] NOT NULL,
[isbuffermanageddynamically] [bit] NOT NULL,
[dbmcheckperioddays] [int] NULL,
[dbmcheckperiodbuffergroup_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ignoredbmuntildate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[notes1] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes2] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes3] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes4] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes5] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes6] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes7] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes8] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes9] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[notes10] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[seasonaleventreferencecode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[seasonaleventtargetstocklevel] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[isarchived] [bit] NOT NULL,
[isobsolete] [bit] NOT NULL,
[currentstocklevel] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[quantityenroute] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[recommendedreplenishmentquantity] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
[bufferpenetrationpercentage] [int] NOT NULL,
[bufferzone] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[bufferpenetrationpercentagereplenishment] [int] NOT NULL,
[bufferzonereplenishment] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_cachedstock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [clusteringkey] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_tbl_cachedstock_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [islivecache] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [tenant_clientnamehere].[tbl_cachedstock] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tbl_cache__isarc__1A200257]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [isarchived]
GO

ALTER TABLE [tenant_clientnamehere].[tbl_cachedstock] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__tbl_cache__isobs__1B142690]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [isobsolete]
GO
```

And the clash (two of which are still in the table) is:

islivecache = 1

id = BA7AD2FD-EFAA-485C-A200-095626C583A3

Comment: .. post the layout/schema, i'm specifically interested in the UNIQUE constraint you claim failed. my first guess is that your UNIQUE constraint is a combo, and that the combos are unique - but we won't know until you post the schema.

Comment: Please provide the DDL of the table, and the data rows that you believe violate a unique constraint in that table.

Comment: @hanshenrik Added schema

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Added schema

Comment: post the hex() of both islivecache and id for all the colliding records, eg ```SELECT hex(islivecache), hex(id) FROM ...```

Comment: @hanshenrik Trying to use the hex function gives "'HEX' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: I your DDL and created in a Azure Sql Db and cannot get duplicates in the table.  Are you absolutely sure that unique constraint is on the table in question - for example if you have different versions (dev, prod, etc. ) maybe that constraint is missing.  Just a thought.  I would consider opening an Azure support request.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this turns out to be very simple - but troubling: every single Unique Key, in every single table, in every single schema, was simultaneously set to "Is Disabled", so whilst they exist they're not being applied.

I've manually cleared out records dupes and rebuilt all indexes to re-enforce the checks, and everything is fine again, but I have no idea how technically this can suddenly occur.

I'm now currently working with Azure support to get to the bottom of it.